# Рандомизация слайдера slick slider. Как сделать?

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

Всем привет! Прошу помочь сделать слайдер так, чтобы при каждой загрузке показывались случайные слайды. Пробовал вот такой код, не получается.

```
function setRandomSlide() {
    var randomSlideId = Math.random() * 46 | 0
    $('.slick-slide').slick('slickGoTo', randomSlideId.toString())
}
$('#slider_team').slick({
      dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000, 
responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно при инициализации слайдера передавать в параметр `initialSlide` (то с какого слайдера будет начинаться отображение) случайное число от нуля до количества слайдов

```
var slidesNumber = $("#slider_team").children().length;
$('#slider_team').slick({
      dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  initialSlide: Math.floor(Math.random() * slidesNumber),
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000, 
responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    ]});
```